# when should I use VS2015 platform toolset V140_XP?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I want to switch from VS2010 to VS2015 but the documentation about V140_XP is not clear to me. I have two questions about it:

1. I use static library(/MT). so I don't need vcruntime140.dll or any other previous runtime library. Should I set platform toolset to V140_XP to run my application in windows XP or not?
2. Will my application run OK on windows 7 and later if I don't set platform toolset to XP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need the `v140_XP` toolset if you're targetting Windows XP machines (which in new applications you should not be doing).

All later versions of Windows (Vista and up) are supported by the `v140` toolset, but applications built with the `v140` toolset will not run under XP.

Comment: Thanks. I got my answer. How/should I accept the answer?

Comment: @MohamadrezaAbdolahzadeh Click the little checkbox (tick) under the up/down arrows on the left of the answer.

Comment: Are there any downsides to using `v140_xp`?

Comment: @JonHatchett From memory you don't get AMP support but otherwise not really.