# C++ DLL Not running on Windows XP when built with Windows 7

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, windows-7, windows-xp

I'm a total newb to c++ but I needed to add some methods to an existing c++ dll.
The dll was originally built with Visual Studio 2008 and it worked on Windows 7 and Windows XP. 
After I added my methods and built the dll again it still worked on Windows 7 but not on XP.
I call the dll from Java and get the following exception:

[image: CLI exception]
After searching around on SO a bit I found Dependency Walker which shows me this:

[image: Dependency Walker]

The command line options for compiling are

`/GS /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Ob1 /Fd".\Release/" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "NTPROCESSDLL_EXPORTS" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0600" /D "_USING_V110_SDK71_" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /GF /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MT /Fa".\Release/" /EHsc /nologo /Fo".\Release/" /Fp".\Release/NTProcessDLL.pch"`

And the linker command is

`/OUT:".\Release\NTProcessDLL.dll" /MANIFEST /PDB:".\Release/NTProcessDLL.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE:NO "pdh.lib" /DEF:".\NTProcessDLL.def" /IMPLIB:".\Release/NTProcessDLL.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:".\Release\NTProcessDLL.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:".\Release\NTProcessDLL.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1`

And the methods I added are these:

```
void _minimizeProcess(long nPid)
{
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProcMinimize, nPid);
}


BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProcMinimize(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND g_HWND = NULL;
    DWORD lpdwProcessId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &lpdwProcessId);
    if (lpdwProcessId == lParam)
    {
        g_HWND = hwnd;
        ShowWindow(g_HWND, SW_MINIMIZE);
        CloseHandle(g_HWND);
        Sleep(1);
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Any help to get this running on XP would be highly appreciated.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This has nothing to do with building on windows 7, it's because you build using VS2015 with the standard toolset which creates executables which don't run on XP. You need the v140_xp toolset e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492695/when-should-i-use-vs2015-platform-toolset-v140-xp

Comment: I actually did that, my platform toolset is set to _Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran into similar problems in the past, those _xp toolsets never worked. Download and install Visual Studio 2010 ([LINK](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/7/24733615-AA11-42E9-8883-E28CDCA88ED5/X16-42552VS2010UltimTrial1.iso)).
Then run your Visual Studio 2015 and go to compiler options, you should have there a new toolset - vs100. Compile your library with that and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that out :)